# Using a dataset

Tags: r, package, dataset

How do I use a data set in R which exists in a package that is not loaded? For example, if I want to use the melanoma data, which is in the `MASS` package, and I write down `melanoma`, it shows an error message: "Object 'melanoma' not found". If I write `data("melanoma")`, ot shows

> Warning Message:
>   In data("melanoma"): data set 'melanoma' not found

How can I use this data set?

Comment: load the package and then get the data `library(MASS)` and `data(Melanoma)` BTW, `R` is case-sensitive

Comment: Or `df1 <- PACKAGE::dataset`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `data(Melanoma, package="MASS")`

Note that R is generally case-sensitive; I had to use `help.search("melanoma")` (which does "fuzzy" rather than exact matching) to figure out that it's called "Melanoma", not "melanoma". (There's also a "melanoma" data set, which might be identical -- I haven't checked -- in the `boot` package.)

As others have noted in comments you can also say `Melanoma <- MASS::Melanoma` (you can assign the data to a different variable if you want, e.g. `my_melanoma <- MASS::Melanoma`).  Or you can just use `MASS::Melanoma` directly in your code, although that will get unwieldy if you have to refer to it a lot.